# Legendre Eigenvalue problem

Tags: eigenfunctions

I have the eigenvalue problem, 
$\frac{d}{dx}\big((1-x^2)\frac{du}{dx}\big)+\lambda u=0$,
on $[-1,1]$ subject to single boundary condiction $u(-1) = u(1)$.
Assume that there is an eigenfunction of the form $u(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2$. Find the possible eigenvalues for such an eigenfunction.
To solve this problem, I plug the $u(x)$ and the 2nd derivative $u(x)$ into the $\frac{d}{dx}\big((1-x^2)\frac{du}{dx}\big)+\lambda u=0$, solve for $x$.
But I couldn't get any eigenvalues. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please use Latex/MathJax to format your post.

Comment: Include your calculations, then someone might help. And you shouldn't solve for $x$, but rather choose $a_0,a_1,a_2$ so that the equality $\frac{d}{dx}\big((1-x^2)\frac{du}{dx}\big)+\lambda u=0$ is true for all $x$.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Hi,sir. Could you please tell me

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz why do I need to solve for a0,a2. Cause on my textbook, they used to solve for x, and get 3 different cases. like lambda greater than zero or less zero or equal zero.

Comment: Well, the thing you're looking for is the function $u$, which is of the form $u(x)=a_0+a_1 x+a_2 x^2$. Thus, finding $u$ is equivalent to finding $a_0,a_1,a_2$. On the other hand, solving for $x$ makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I assume it is sufficiently late I am not doing your homework for you. The boundary condition tells you that $a_1=0$, so it's missing from your Ansatz. Plugging the surviving piece into the equation yields
$$
\partial ((1-x^2)2a_2)=-\lambda(a_0+a_2x^2),
$$
so, comparing powers, $\lambda=6$ and $a_2=-3a_0$.

In fact, do you now see how your particular case (*n*=2) falls into the general order-*n* polynomial solution
$$
P_n\propto \partial^n (x^2-1)^n
$$ 
of 
$$
P_n(x)= \partial ((1-x^2)\partial P_n) +n(n+1)P_n=0  ~~?
$$